# ActiveMQ connection Url for Blob Messages

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I my application i have a remote ActiveMQ server and embedded ActiveMQ Server. When i send text messages it's working. But when i try to send Blob messages it throws a  `javax.jms.JMSException` caused by `java.net.MalformedURLException` and `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

**My Broker URL**

```
String broker1 = "tcp://localhost:7005?jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl=http://localhost:61617";
```

where `tcp://localhost:7005` is an embedded broker, and `http://localhost:61617` is a remote broker.

**My Producer code**

```
File file=new File("C:/Users/xxx/Downloads/1234.txt");

ActiveMQConnection connection = ActiveMQConnection.makeConnection(broker);
connection.start();
ActiveMQSession session = (ActiveMQSession) connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
// Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
Destination destination = session.createQueue("test");
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

BlobMessage message = session.createBlobMessage(file);
System.out.println("upload started");
producer.send(message);
System.out.println("upload finished");
session.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: I think you should use `jms.blobTransferPolicy.uploadUrl` and not `jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl`. Please refer to: http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html

Answer (score 0):

URL should be like this `embededbroker?jms.blobTransferPolicy.defaultUploadUrl=externalurl`

In case of failure in embedded URL then external URL will be used.By default activemq provides a file server in this link `http://(activemq server ip):portnumber/fileserver`

For example if your activemq server running on localhost url should be `http://localhost:8161/fileserver/`
It

It supports HTTP or FTP or SCP or some other point-to-point protocol.